# Enable CORS in wordpress

Tags: http

I'm trying to enable CORS in wordpress and I've placed this line of code in my header.php file

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Then I tested to see if it works via this page http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client

The response I get is:

```
Fired XHR event: loadstart
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: error

XHR status: 0
XHR status text: 
Fired XHR event: loadend
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, anybody able to help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Headers manipulation should be done before template output starts. In WordPress it is typically done in [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook, which is right before template load but after core has fully loaded.

Comment: I read this article which recommended me putting the code in the header.php file  http://bowdenweb.com/wp/2011/05/how-to-enable-cors-in-wordpress.html

Comment: While _technically_ that should work since it's before any output, I would consider it somewhat dirty approach to use template like that. Aside from it if that is your implementation it header _should_ probably work and your issue is something else.

Comment: wayback machine reference to overcome linkrot: https://web.archive.org/web/20140314152828/http://bowdenweb.com:80/wp/2011/05/how-to-enable-cors-in-wordpress.html